# Linux on eMMC - Corrupt file system

Tags: hardware, ext4, postgresql, fsck

Today, the root files system on my hardware running Ubuntu was set to readonly, because the file system had some internal trouble.

I found this with `dmesg`

```
[18471.780031] sdhci: Timeout waiting for Buffer Read Ready interrupt during tuning procedure, falling back to fixed sampling clock
[18481.816797] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
[18481.818821] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[18481.818866] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 0 at /build/linux-W6HB68/linux-4.4.0/drivers/mmc/host/sdhci.c:1017 sdhci_send_command+0x714/0xc30 [sdhci]()
[18481.818877] Modules linked in: xhci_plat_hcd nls_iso8859_1 dwc3 udc_core ulpi intel_rapl intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd input_leds uas usb_storage lpc_ich shpchp snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core snd_soc_sst_mfld_platform snd_soc_core mei_txe snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine mei snd_pcm dwc3_pci snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq dw_dmac snd_seq_device dw_dmac_core 8250_fintek snd_timer snd intel_hid sparse_keymap soundcore i2c_designware_platform i2c_designware_core tpm_crb spi_pxa2xx_platform pwm_lpss_platform 8250_dw pwm_lpss int3400_thermal int3403_thermal int340x_thermal_zone acpi_thermal_rel mac_hid acpi_pad parport_pc
[18481.819271]  ppdev lp parport autofs4 hid_generic usbhid hid mmc_block i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm r8169 mii fjes video sdhci_acpi sdhci pinctrl_cherryview
[18481.819423] CPU: 1 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/1 Tainted: G        W       4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu
[18481.819435] Hardware name: AAEON UP-CHT01/UP-CHT01, BIOS UPC1BM0S 06/04/2016
[18481.819447]  0000000000000086 7f0cf1c4636dff29 ffff88017fc83d28 ffffffff813f7c63
[18481.819468]  0000000000000000 ffffffffc0047460 ffff88017fc83d60 ffffffff810812d2
[18481.819487]  ffff88017aa2f540 ffff880176779ad8 0000000000000010 0000000000000001
[18481.819506] Call Trace:
[18481.819521]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff813f7c63>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
[18481.819571]  [<ffffffff810812d2>] warn_slowpath_common+0x82/0xc0
[18481.819588]  [<ffffffff8108141a>] warn_slowpath_null+0x1a/0x20
[18481.819612]  [<ffffffffc0044914>] sdhci_send_command+0x714/0xc30 [sdhci]
[18481.819634]  [<ffffffff81404dbb>] ? __const_udelay+0x2b/0x30
[18481.819656]  [<ffffffffc0041d49>] ? sdhci_reset+0x59/0xc0 [sdhci]
[18481.819679]  [<ffffffffc0044f32>] sdhci_finish_data+0x102/0x350 [sdhci]
[18481.819702]  [<ffffffffc0045180>] ? sdhci_finish_data+0x350/0x350 [sdhci]
[18481.819724]  [<ffffffffc00451fb>] sdhci_timeout_timer+0x7b/0xc0 [sdhci]
[18481.819746]  [<ffffffff810ecd55>] call_timer_fn+0x35/0x120
[18481.819768]  [<ffffffffc0045180>] ? sdhci_finish_data+0x350/0x350 [sdhci]
[18481.819785]  [<ffffffff810ed70a>] run_timer_softirq+0x23a/0x2f0
[18481.819808]  [<ffffffff81085db1>] __do_softirq+0x101/0x290
[18481.819828]  [<ffffffff810860b3>] irq_exit+0xa3/0xb0
[18481.819847]  [<ffffffff8183b0a2>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x42/0x50
[18481.819868]  [<ffffffff81839362>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x82/0x90
[18481.819876]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff816cb5d1>] ? cpuidle_enter_state+0x111/0x2b0
[18481.819913]  [<ffffffff816cb7a7>] cpuidle_enter+0x17/0x20
[18481.819934]  [<ffffffff810c4522>] call_cpuidle+0x32/0x60
[18481.819950]  [<ffffffff816cb783>] ? cpuidle_select+0x13/0x20
[18481.819969]  [<ffffffff810c47e0>] cpu_startup_entry+0x290/0x350
[18481.819989]  [<ffffffff81051784>] start_secondary+0x154/0x190
[18481.820005] ---[ end trace 3081f620d5ceb477 ]---
[18481.822972] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x400900
[18481.823076] mmcblk0: error -110 transferring data, sector 26544216, nr 136, cmd response 0x0, card status 0x0
[18481.823131] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544216
[18481.823156] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544224
[18481.823173] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544232
[18481.823202] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544240
[18481.823219] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544248
[18481.823234] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544256
[18481.823250] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544264
[18481.823291] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544272
[18481.823309] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544280
[18481.823336] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 26544288
[18481.823622] Aborting journal on device mmcblk0p2-8.
[18481.827415] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[18481.827446] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): Remounting filesystem read-only
[18481.829542] EXT4-fs error (device mmcblk0p2): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
```

I am running owncloud with PostgreSQL on the hardware.

What could be the root of this problem?

It happened for the third time in two days ...

Please tell me, if you need more information (cat /proc/???)

The partition `/dev/mmcblk0p2` is the root file system (eMMC).

I guess I was too naive. It looks that running Linux on eMMC needs some special considerations: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136269/corruption-proof-sd-card-filesystem-for-embedded-linux

I guess that PostgreSQL does too much file system operations, to drive the file system on eMMC "crazy".

This is my hardware: Intel Cherry Trail x5-Z8350, On board DDR3L 4GB memory, On board 32GB eMMC storage http://up-shop.org/home/81-up-gws01w4g-memory32g-emmc-boardwo-vesa-plate.html

## Question

How can I know if the hardware is broken?

Or is running Linux with postgres on eMMC a bad idea in general?

## Update

After following the hints from [this answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/169/how-can-i-extend-the-life-of-my-sd-card/186#186), I could sync via owncloud for hours, and no file system error occurs. This is no big surprise since now only very few io-operations happen on the eMMC. Here is what I did:

- attach external tradition hard disk
- put postgres and /var/log on external disk
- disable swap
- use ramfs for /tmp

But above questions still remain.

Comment: It looks like you have a mounted SD card that is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Your SD may be corrupted or worse faulty.
Open a terminal (Applications-Accessories-Terminal) and give the command
sudo fsck -a /dev/mmcblk0p1 (Replace /dev/mmcblk0p1 with the actual partition device for the micro sd card). fsck = File Systen ChecKer.

If the fsck is successful, it will not return any output.
In this case I'd try to format it again.

my 2 cents

Comment: I get errors on "/dev/mmcblk0p2". Unfortunately this is the root filesystem. Is there a way to check it's state live (while it is active)?

Comment: can you boot from a live distro ? in this case you fsck the volume